# How to search data in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, sqldatasource, sqlcommand

I need help with my asp.net web app. I have a page where i display data (all the users) with datagrid. For now, there is no problem when i only have a few users in. But when a database will be populated with 100+ users, it will be difficult to find specified users.

I need to create a search engine (search by name). I already found a few tutorials, but they are all based on creating a new datagrid and creating a new sql data source.

I need to make sure that when admin types in data to find members, it display the searched user in the same datagrid. I already have a code for delete and edit data, can somebody please help me create a code or at least guide me, how to make a search engine? Thank you

Here is my code:

```
<asp:CommandField CancelText="Cancel" DeleteText="Delete" EditText="Edit" ShowDeleteButton="true" SelectText="Select" UpdateText="Update" ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Users] WHERE [Id] = @Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] ([Id], [Name], [LastName],) VALUES (@Id, @Name, @LastName,)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Users]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Users] SET [Name] = @Name, [LastName] = @LastName, WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

EDIT:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Id" Visible="false" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" >                    
                <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="lastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="lastName" >
                <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
                <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: hv u kept textbox and button for search ???

Comment: yes i have a textbox for search and a button

Comment: Can i hv ur code for binding grid....

Comment: @X-Developer i edit my post. is this what u u wanted?

Comment: Change your select command in order to filter by Name. SELECT * FROM [Users] where Name=@Name

Comment: yeah but that will only order them. im trying to create a search machine to search inside all of them and only displaying the searched user

Comment: try Filter Expressions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/59bfya48(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Filter Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/59bfya48%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Modify your SqlDatasource as

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Users] WHERE [Id] = @Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Users] ([Id], [Name], [LastName],) VALUES (@Id, @Name, @LastName,)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Users]" FilterExpression="Name LIKE '%{0}%' UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Users] SET [Name] = @Name, [LastName] = @LastName, WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
<FilterParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="%" />
            </FilterParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Add

```
FilterExpression="Name LIKE '%{0}%'
```

AND

```
<FilterParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="%" />
</FilterParameters>
```

Please replace that the txtSearch I used for ControlID with the ID of your textbox which is used for search.

Comment: thank you thank you this is perfect. thank you thousand times!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need to filter by Name the Grid Results. First of all Change your Select query to add a Filter.

```
SELECT * FROM [Users] where ((not @Name is null and [Name] like '%' + @Name + '%'))
```

Then add a Control parameter to your SqlDatasource:

```
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextboxName" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Then add to your search button this code behind:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: yes this is exactly what im trying to do, but when i click "search", nothing happens. Im afraid that searchbox (textbox) and button aren't connected ?

Comment: @fkr can u use asp textbox and button outside the grid ?? instead of using control parameters....

Comment: Hi again. @ZedBee already gave me the right answer, but yours was very very helpful too. Thank you very much for your help and your time. Your input was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use [backgrid](http://backgridjs.com/)

for avoiding multiple datasources it performs client side filtering and vary fast.